# How to load traits via composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, traits

I have tried add my traits folder to composer custom autoload but this is doesn't work and returns an error. So is this possible autoload traits via composer? Many thanks for any answer.

My trait:

```
trait User
{
  public function is_email_unique($email)
  {
    return $this->User->get_one_by_email($email) ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }  

  public function is_username_unique($username)
  {
    return $this->User->get_one_by_username($username) ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }
}
```

My class:

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller 
{
      // Implement trait in class
  use User;

  public function __contstruct()
  {
    parent::__contstruct();
  }

  public function register()
  {
    if ($this->input->is_post()) {

        // load validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', "Username", 'required|callback_username_check');

        // There I use my trait method callback_is_email_unique
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', "Email", 'required|valid_email|callback_is_email_unique');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', "Password", 'required|matches[confirm_password]|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', "Confirm password", 'required');

  ...
 }
}
```

My composer file:

```
{    
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "User": "Validation"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code that you're using? Post a minimal example of what doesn't work and say exactly what you're seeing that shows it isn't working.

Comment: Traits are loaded the same way as classes.  You can generate a classmap, or use a PSR style.

Comment: That isn't going to resolve as you have defined.  The `PSR-0` option accepts `"NS-Prefix": "Path"`  Assuming your source directory is `Validation` to load a trait `\User` you need to have `"": "Validation"`

Comment: Hmmz, but if I try request class with same configuration this works fine but not with trait?

Comment: So Steve Buzonas your assumption is not correct because if I change trait keyword to class and request this class system works correct.

Comment: It is important to know where your files are located relative to the `composer.json`. And also please confirm that you are using PHP 5.4.

Comment: Hi Sven, no I use php 5.5, my path is correct because if I shall change trait keyword to class the code autoload fine and works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested back and forth some time now with PHP 5.5.3, and while I have to report that during testing things looked broken (more likely due to me producing a VM with that version on short notice, with no settings and the wronk keyboard layout), in the end I cannot reproduce the error. I'd say that autoloading for traits works as advertised.

Now here is what I did:

In the home directory:

```
composer.json

{
    "autoload": {"psr-0":{"User":"src"}}
}
```

Also:

```
test.php

<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

class Auth {
    use User;
}

new Auth;
```

In the directory `src`:

```
src/User.php

<?php

trait User {}
```

Running `composer install` creates `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` with this array entry:

```
'User' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
```

And executing the testscript works for me.

Note that it is important to have the naming of the files correct. They have to match exactly according to PSR-0 rules (or PSR-4 if you prefer using namespaces), including case sensitive correct filenames.

If you have a trait named "User", and you define PSR-0 autoloading like "User": "Validation", the expected situation would be that the following file exists: `Validation/User.php` with the content:

```
<?php

trait User {
    // stuff here
}
```

This trait will then be able to be autoloaded after running at least once `composer install`.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed description on composer and autoloading traits. This was a question from google results, and I believed it to be related to the issue I was having so I made a bounty.

Turns out, the php.ini of my web service was allowing short tags, and my CLI php.ini was not, so one `<?` instead of a `<?php` was killing the whole thing.

Anyways, for an amazing answer to help the community, have 100 rep.